# Geoserver + WebService

Tags: geoserver

We are building application based on GIS data. We are planning to use PostGIS for storing GIS data.
We will be having API layer which is in java and which consumes webservices rest/soap.
We also using QGIS as UI frontend.
We need to deploy this application.
Can we use GeoServer for deploying java application. What is performance issue if number of users are more.Can we use REST/SOAP webservices in Geoserver.
Any good link/resource/example would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use GeoServer to deploy your Java application.

GeoServer can be downloaded with 2 main configurations (see http://geoserver.org/release/stable/)

1. A platform independent binary that comes with Jetty
2. A WAR file which you can run in your own servlet container (like Tomcat)

You can use a variety of servlet containers (ex: Jetty or Tomcat) to deploy your own Java application along with GeoServer.

GeoServer has a thorough REST interface:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/

GeoServer has many options to optimize performance for a production environment with many users.
See:

https://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/geoserver-in-production-we-do-it-here-is-how-foss4g-2016
https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/educational/en/adv_gsconfig/gsproduction.html